# Using index to extract substring from an array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, indexing, extract

I would like to use perl to extract 30 character substrings from an array, using another array that consists of indices where I would like the substring from each line to start. For instance, Line 1 extract 30 characters starting at position 21, line 2 starting at 5, line 3 ... etc. Is this possible? I know its easy to do with a fixed index but I have never tried using indices stored in a separate array. 
Thanks so much.

For example, Array 1 would consist of strings for instance in my case:

```
ATGTCAAATCCAGAAAGCTTGAAAAAACAGGTTGAACCTCCTGGTTACAATGAGTTATTTATGGTGGAAGATGTTTGTAATGTGGACCTAGAGCAGGGACT
TGATTTGTGTAAGCCTGAAAAGGTAAACAAACAATCTCAACGATCTCGACAATCCCGACAATCCCTCTTTACCAACACCATTAAGCCTCAAAAAGACAAGA
TGAATATTAAAACAAATAAAATAAAAGAGTTTTTAAATGACCTTTTTACTGAATTTTCTAAATTCCACAATAGCTATTATCCTAATGGAAGAATTTCTACT
CAGGACAAATCTCGATGGGTCTTGCTTATTATTTGGTCTATTATCACTATTTTAACAATAGACAAGAAATTTAAAATAAAAGAGTCATATTTAGAATGGAT
AGGTGAAAATCAGTCCCACAGTGAAATTTGGGGGCCTATTGTTATTTATGTTGGCTTATTCATACTCTTATTGTCTGCTTTTAACTGTACGTTTCCTTCAC
```

And Array two consists of indices that I want to start each 30 char substring I extract from such as

```
21
32
15
7
17
```

Leaving an output of:

```
AAAAAACAGGTTGAACCTCCTGGTTACAAT
AATCTCAACGATCTCGACAATCCCGACAAT
ATAAAATAAAAGAGTTTTTAAATGACCTTT
AATCTCGATGGGTCTTGCTTATTATTTGGT
CAGTGAAATTTGGGGGCCTATTGTTATTTA
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand you. Could you perhaps show code that you tried but didn't work as expected? Actual example data (instead of a description of this data) plus the expected output would help as well.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume we have a string, and an offset:

```
my $string = "ATGTCAAATCCAGAAAGCTTGAAAAAACAGGTTGAACCTCCTGGTTACAATGAGTTATTTATGGTGGAAGATGTTTGTAATGTGGACCTAGAGCAGGGACT";
my $offset = 21;
my $length = 30;
```

We can then get the required substring like

```
substr $string, $offset, $length;
```

But if we have an array `@strings` and a corresponding array `@offsets`, then for the *i*-th element we have:

```
substr $strings[$i], $offsets[$i], $length;
```

When we loop over all indices of the arrays (`0 .. $#strings`), we can get each substring.